# Is there a better way to rename data frame columns in R

Tags: r

I want to rename a column in data frame but want to avoid the absolute index (because the data frame may have additional columns later.)

Instead, I want to use "from column name" and "to column name". Is there a better way than this?

```
names(mtcars)[which(names(mtcars)=='cyl')]='cylindar'
```

Comment: You can omit `which` to simply `names(mtcars)[names(mtcars)=='cyl']='cylindar'`

Comment: I don't know what "better" means but there are `rename` and `setnames` functions in dplyr and data.table which have a bit cleaner syntax perhaps

Comment: in addition to this there are `rename()` functions in `plyr` and `dplyr` (with **opposite conventions**!)